# How to access error details in MSBuild

Tags: .net, msbuild

I'm creating MSBuild Project that will send a detailed email when an error occurs. I am using a Mail Task from MsBuild Community Tasks package. But I don't know how to pass error details to this task - is there any predefined variable with error or something ?

```
<Target Name="All">
  <CallTarget Targets="DoSomething" />
  <OnError ExecuteTargets="ErrorEmail"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="ErrorEmail">
  <Mail SmtpServer="mysrv" From="me@mysrv" To="error@mysrv" Subject="An error occured"
      Body="Error details: " />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only predefined property would be $(MSBuildLastTaskResult), but it in your example will only ever have the value "false" which isn't useful.  You'll need to either set up an error property inside DoSomething, or else ensure that a log file has been created (see msbuild file logger parameters) and send the log file contents in the email.  Consider something like this:

```
> msbuild MyProject.proj /fl /flp:v=detailed;logfile=mylog.txt

<Target Name="ErrorEmail">
   <ReadLinesFromFile
      File="mylog.txt"
      Lines="_ErrorLines"
      />
   <Mail
      SmtpServer="mysrv"
      From="me@mysrv"
      To="error@mysrv"
      Subject="An error occured"
      Body="Error details: @(_ErrorLines, '%0D%0A')"
      />
</Target>
```

Comment: Nice, but got this error:   c:\AccuRev\Build_2012_01_02\ASA.Core.Services\ErrorHandlers.targets(24,9): er
ror MSB3501: Could not read lines from file "mylog.txt". The process cannot
access the file 'c:\AccuRev\Build_2012_01_02\ASA.Core.Services\mylog.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Started new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728883/email-errors-in-msbuild-readlinesfromfile-is-being-used-by-another-process