# Email Errors in MSBuild - ReadLinesFromFile "is being used by another process"

Tags: msbuild, error-handling, email

I'm trying to implement the answer from here: 
[How to access error details in MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843997/how-to-access-error-details-in-msbuild)

```
> msbuild MyProject.proj /fl /flp:v=detailed;logfile=mylog.txt

<Target Name="ErrorEmail">
   <ReadLinesFromFile
      File="mylog.txt"
      Lines="_ErrorLines"
      />
   <Mail
      SmtpServer="mysrv"
      From="me@mysrv"
      To="error@mysrv"
      Subject="An error occured"
      Body="Error details: @(_ErrorLines, '%0D%0A')"
      />
</Target>
```

Looks elegant, but I'm getting this error:

> c:\AccuRev\Build_2012_01_02\MyApp\ErrorHandlers.targets(24,9):
>   error MSB3501: Could not read lines from file "mylog.txt". The
>   process cannot access the file
>   'c:\AccuRev\Build_2012_01_02\MyApp\mylog.txt' because it
>   is being used by another process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mylog.txt file is locked because you are using the same file for build log and for the ReadLinesFromFile task.

EDIT: Try to execute MSBuild 2 times. First to build your projects and 2nd time to send an email. Use [distributedFileLogger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) command line switch with /flp1:logfile=errors.txt;errorsonly command line parameters to log all errors to errors.txt. You can then attach this file into your email without sending whole build log.

Comment: Isn't that the goal?  I want to email my log of errors. You're right, of course it's locked.  My question is how to get it to work?

Comment: Then the further trick would be to not send an email if it succeeded.

Comment: I'm going to try your approach.  So it looks like the code posted by the other guy in the other post would never work then?

Comment: Yes. It seems like it was never tested.

Comment: errors.txt file is always created. errors file is empty if no errors are reported during build process. You can check if build failed using [ReadLinesFromFile task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164299.aspx) on errors.txt file. If the Lines output parameter is empty, you don't have to send error report.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late for the party, but I was struggling with this myself: How to access the error log in order to attach it to an email? Was getting the same message--the error log file couldn't be accessed to attach it, or even to read it.

The solution? [Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) the log file and then send the copy. Worked like a charm. My code looks something like this:

```
<Target Name="FailBuild">
  <Copy SourceFiles="errors.txt" DestinationFiles="errors_email.txt" />
  <Mail SmtpServer="$(SmtpEmailServer)"
      ...
      Attachments="errors_email.txt" />
</Target>
```